# Android version icloud dropbox (file auto synchronization & clouding epub)

Tags: android, synchronization, rsync

I'm university student.

I'm doing some cloud project, which is exactly android version iCloud and iBooks app.

Development enviroments:

- Server model: epoll server(C lanuage)
- File management: Hadoop
- Clients: android(java) and windows PC(C#)

Restirction: 
No use dropbox API (I have to construct my own server and clients)

Situation:

File auto synchonization and Clouding ebook viewer like icloud(or dropbox) and iBooks app.

When you take photo in your android smartphone, it goes automatically

in your android tablet and your Windows PC as "real pic file", not the file name lists only.

My question is:

1. What technology is applied into icloud or dropbox?

How can i notice new files and file changing automatically?

2 We use 3 different programming lanugages C, C#, java in server clients each.

What networking problem should i consider and will meet?

Searched information utill now:

1. rsync(librync)
2. zookeeper(sub project of hadoop)

Answer (score 0):

I would use Amazon Web Services to accomplish this task. You can use Amazon S3 to store the files (this is actually what DropBox uses).

Comment: Thanks your quick response, but it uploaded while typing:( there is restriction. I have consturct server too, using hadoop concept.